# use manytomany field in both the models Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models named `Profile` and `Controversy`. My requirement is many people can be involved in a controversy and a single person can have multiple Controversies. With that said, I feel like I should a `ManyToMany` field in both the models but I'm guessing that violates `ManyToMany` fields documentation as it should be used in only model.

my models are as follows :

```
class Profile(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Controversy = models.ManyToManyField(Controversy) # As one person can have multiple controveries


class Controversy(models.Model):
    year = models.Datefield()
    other_people_involved = models.ManytoManyField(profile) # As multiple people can be involved in a controversy
    description = models.TextField()
```

This obviously will throw error.
I'm not able to understand as to how to tackle such a scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

Create another model to store the `person` and `controvery` connection.

```
class Profile(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Controversy(models.Model):
    year = models.Datefield()
    description = models.TextField()

class PeopleInvolved(models.Model):
    controversy = models.ManyToManyField(Controversy)
    person = models.ManytoManyField(profile)
```

So to list the controversies of a person do this:

```
controversies = [i.controversy for i in PeopleInvolved.objects.filter(person=[profile_id])] #pass the profile id of the person.
```

And to list the people involved in a controversy do this:

```
peoples = [i.person for i in PeopleInvolved.objects.filter(controversy=[controversy_id])] #pass the controversy id.
```